# How to tell if a website is using next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

It's easy to tell if a website uses ReactJS, by using the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi).

However, I know a website that uses ReactJS and Server Side Rendering (the whole page is built with React components, but the page source contains the whole HTML). **Is it possible to tell if this website uses [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) in particular for SSR?**

Does Next.js leave any trace detectable on the front-end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are seeing content is wrapped with id="__next", this website use next.js

like uber

[image]

and like netflix

[image]

Comment: Now I don't see id="__next" on the Uber and Netflix sites.

Answer (score 10):

Version of Next.js + properties of the page:

```js
console.log({
  NextJSVersion: window.next?.version,
  pageProps: window.__NEXT_DATA__?.props?.pageProps
})
```

Answer (score 8):

By default, Next.js sets the `X-Powered-By` header to `Next.js`. So if you check Chrome's devtools for a page, you can check to see if this header exists.

**Note**: [Developers can opt-out of including this header](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/disabling-x-powered-by). So if the header does not exist, it is not evidence that the website does not use Next.js

[image]