# Using browser console, how to tell if a site is using Next.js or Create React Rpp

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

If you know a site is using react in some way, how can you, just using the javascript console, identify if the app is running a next.js app or create react app.

Comment: NextJS usually attach an `id` with value `__next` in the body, so you can inspect with the elements tab and check it out. As for the CRA, I don't really know if there's something similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a website is using next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341465/how-to-tell-if-a-website-is-using-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this. But to my knowledge, one of the important feature of `next.js` is that it supports SSR.

If we fetch the url of the page using `postman`, sites developed using react app will return a html with javascript files, where as those ones with `next.js` or with SSR mode returns a complete page. I think it might be worthy to fetch the url and check if the response contains `"Need to enable javascript"` or something like that. This might not completely show that the site is built `create-react-app` or `next.js` but can help you to discriminate them.